# Symfony2 Embedded forms How to assign values of certain form fields to child form field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have entity User and entity Company.

Relations are Company (one) to User (many).

When I signup as a company I need both these objects to be created.

Both objects have same properties: **$phone, $firstName, $lastName;**
(for company those fields mean main contact person).

My registration form consists of 2 forms: user form and embedded company form.

**Problem**: Now when I render signup form I have duplicated fields:
 phone, firstName, lastName rendered for each object.

Is there a way to combine them somehow and ask for those values from user only once but still to save them into database for both entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem using event listeners on PRE_SUBMIT event:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

/**
 * Class CompanyRegFormType
 * @package AppBundle\Form
 */
class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', 'text')
            ->add('lastName', 'text')
            ->add('phone', 'text')
            ->add('company', new CompanyFormType())
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event){
                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $data['company']['phone'] = $data['phone'];
                    $data['company']['firstName'] = $data['firstName'];
                    $data['company']['lastName'] = $data['lastName'];
                    $event->setData($data);
                }
              );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        ]);
    }
}
```